# Highlighting a part of 3D model using Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d-model

I have a 3D model that has to be displayed in an html page. I have done that and I am able to move it around 360 degree as well. Now, I need to highlight specific parts. For eg: if the object is aircraft and if I click a button "Tail", it should highlight me the tail. Please see the pic.

[image]

Can I achieve this using Three.js? Can you give me some ideas? Or, should I need to add some elements in the 3D model and refer it via code?

Comment: Open the model in the three.js editor and see whether the tail is a separate mesh of the model. Select it in your code and change it's properties

Answer (score 1):

Depends how the plane geometry was exported.

- If the whole plane is a single Mesh, then you might need to swap out its regular texture with one that highlights the tail (or whatever part you need highlighted). This means you’d need one new texture per part you want highlighted.
- If the plane is made up of separate Meshes, then you could change the material of the tail mesh for a brighter one with something like:

  `tail.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff9900});`